# promise doesn't work, how to use catch in this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, middleware

I'm trying to use promise to make error message to the console when Mongo connection doesn't work.
i get an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')
how can i fix it? it supposed to work like that.
i can use try & catch block but i prefer to know how to use it this way and what is wrong

```javascript
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreatIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DB conecttion successful')
    .catch(() => console.log('Error'));
  });

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app runing on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catch` should be after `then` not after `console`.

`console.log` will return undefined as it `void` function, that why the error `"Cannot read properties of undefined"` appear

```
mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreatIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('DB conecttion successful')
  }).catch(() => console.log('Error'));;

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app runing on port ${port}`);
});
```